# Why does mailx send a previous version of its referenced file instead of the latest one?

Tags: bash, unix, scripting

I've created a simple script that will automatically kill the top 2 processes. But before the restart, I write the top 10 list of processes to a text file and its memory status (free -h) before it kills the top 2 processes. However, when it sends the email, it doesn't take the latest file but the last updated file. The txt file overwrites every time the script is ran.

```
file=$aa_dir/tst_topprocess.txt #file for top processes
file_chk=$aa_dir/tst_membefore.txt #file for previous memory check
topproc=$(more "$file")
memchk=$(more "$file_chk")


 if [[ "$memtst" -le  "$threshold" ]]; then #for testing
    echo -e "`date` \n $top" > $file  #writes top processes before to a file
    echo -e "`date` \n $chk" > $file_chk #writes free -h results to a file
    #sleep 5
    #restart here
    echo "Killing PIDs..."
    #kill -9 $pid1 $pid2
    sleep 5
    echo -e  Memory check before restart: \n \n $memchk  \n \n Top processes before the restart: \n \n $topproc \n \n Processes after the restart: \n \n $top \n \n `date`" | mailx -s "$subject" -r "$mail_from" abc@gmail.com
```

The result is:
it does save the processes before killing the pid but when it sends the email, it doesn't get the latest file. It sends the contents from the previous run.

So for example, if the script runs via cronjob every 15 minutes, the file that would be displayed on the email body for the 11:00 pm run would be 10:45pm.

What am I missing? How do I tell the script to get the latest saved file?

Comment: `memchk=$(more "$file_chk")` -> `echo $memchk`? Would you expect `memchk` to "auto-change"?

Comment: Memchk would change everytime the script is ran. Reason why I'm saving it on a text file is because I want to view the pids before and after the restart. Also I used *nore* so that the memcheck generated file would display on the email body

Comment: `Memchk would change everytime the script is ra` but you do `memchk=$(.. file_chk)` _and after it_ you do `echo -e "`date` \n $chk" > $file_chk``. || Please do not use backticks - use `$(..)` instead. Check your script with https://shellcheck.net

Comment: Yes! That is what I should have done. Thank you!

Corrected this part, so now it's displaying correctly.
topproc=$(echo -e "`date` \n $top" > "$file")
memchk=$(echo -e "`date` \n $chk" > "$file_chk")
topproc2=$(more "$file")
memchk2=$(more "$file_chk")

Answer (score 0):

Per @KamilCuk's suggestion, I changed this part of the code to fix the issue

topproc=$(echo -e "`date` \n $top" > "$file")
memchk=$(echo -e "`date` \n $chk" > "$file_chk")
topproc2=$(more "$file")
memchk2=$(more "$file_chk")